# SQL Azure Migration Wizard - small extra step needed?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I've recently migrated a couple of SQL 2008 databases to Azure using the 3.7 Migration Wizard from CodePlex.

After completing the migration, everything works well, except that I don't have all the "normal" right click menu items in Management Studio - e.g. I don't have "Design", "Select Top 1000", etc

I think the reason that these items is missing is because the logged in user (my SQL Azure admin) is not a user of the migrated database - or maybe its something else? If I just create a database and a table inside SQL Azure then I do seem to have these menus.

Is there a way to get these right-click menu items back on the migrated database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to say it, but that's not a feature of a database migrated to SQL Azure, that's a feature of all SQL Azure Databases.  Some options in in SQL Management Studio just aren't available.  For example right click on a stored procedure -> Script Stored Procedure To -> Alter is disabled for some unknown reason.

Comment: This is like the most annoying "feature" of SQL Azure :/

Comment: I don't know, I'd just gotten used to having intellisense in SSMS then I switched to SQL Azure

Comment: Thanks for the answers... I'm still holding out in hope that there's some magic setting or permission... I can hope!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there are a lot of unnecessary obstacles to the SQL Azure platform (among others, the issues listed in this question), why I hope Microsoft with the upcoming Denali will give the DB-admins and developers their well beloved tools back in its fullest.

It is very frustrating not being able to use what one has been acquainted to use with SQL Server Management Studio .. this also applies for the SQL Compact Edition 4.0.

Thank you for asking the question, +1.