# SSMS Object Explorer - Select Top N Rows missing when connected to Azure DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

I just upgraded my SSMS to 2008 R2. I'm missing the option to select the top 1000 rows from a table, like this:

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

I know how to change the number of rows that are displayed, but the options aren't there at all. I saw that someone submitted a bug for this a few years ago, but there was no workaround, and I'm not sure what to do. Any ideas?

**EDIT - Azure Problem?**

I just used SSMS to open my local SQL Server, and I get the option to select the top 100 rows. But in my other SSMS instance, the one that is connected to my Azure DB, I don't see it. Is it possibly an Azure limitation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221660/sql-azure-migration-wizard-small-extra-step-needed), I believe it is a limitation of SQL Azure. I have not been able to find any additional information that would allow you to work around the issue.

Comment: That answer is almost two years old, so I hope it's no longer correct. :) Anyway, if no one can tell me otherwise, I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SpectralGhost is correct; Azure doesn't allow SSMS to query data in the same way as SQL Server, as they're still not the same product.  Simply write a SELECT statement to bring back the 200 or so records you want/need.

Comment: It is now available on SqlServer Mgt Studio 2014.  I also added an answer to this post for ease of searching.  And I have not downloaded the hotfix but I do see it listed as a fix.

Comment: It is NOT a limitation of SQL Azure, it is a limitation of your client or SSMS version.

Answer (score 4):

As of 06/04/2015 MS has published a hotfix to solve this issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011055

"An update is available that enables "Select Top 1000 Rows" option for tables and views of SQL Azure database"

Comment: Prefer downloading the Service Pack 2 update: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168

Comment: The download link is no more valid. You can download Service Pack 2 as @webStuff suggested

Answer (score 2):

You do not have this option in SSMS while working with SQL Azure, you have to exexute the query yourself ... *select top 10000 from tablename*

There are few other options as well in SSMS which are not displayed in case of SQL Azure.

This is an excpected behaviour for SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

It is now available on SqlServer Mgt Studio 2014.

Comment: Only available in SSMS 2014 for build greater than 12.0.20xx.x
You can install the Service Pack 2 (build 12.0.50000.0) if you have a older build: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have correct values in the SQL Server Object Explorer Settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my settings are exactly like that.

Comment: I just edited my question to provide more information. Possibly an Azure issue?