# Performing standard SSMS tasks on Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I connected SSMS to an Azure database. Now I can't easily select top rows by right clicking, can't design views, etc.... like I can with local SQL Server databases. How can I get this functionality for an Azure database? Thanks

Comment: Have you read this: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/connecting-sql-azure-sql

Comment: Yes @Tanner. I'm already connected fine to the Azure db view SSMS. The issues is that several standard options/functions are not available for Azure tables/views, etc..

Comment: See this answer and the link it references: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14764234/57475

Answer (score 2):

If you have not done so, please [update to v12 of Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-plan-prepare-upgrade/) and also please make sure you install the [latest updates for SSMS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3031047). These updates will allow you to right-click on a table to "Select top 1000 rows", "Edit top 200 rows", or open "Design".